# Получить список переменных шаблона Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Здравствуйте.
Есть ли возможность в Jinja API прочитать шаблон и получить список переменных вида {{ var }}, которые в нем используются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу себе сам.

В модуле jinja2.meta есть функция find_undeclared_variables, которая по построенному дереву AST определяет, каких переменных не хватает.

В документации есть [пример](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#the-meta-api) использования:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Environment, meta
>>> env = Environment()
>>> ast = env.parse('{% set foo = 42 %}{{ bar + foo }}')
>>> meta.find_undeclared_variables(ast) == set(['bar'])
True
```